# Access harddrive using assembly

Tags: assembly, bios

Where can I find out how to address the hard drive directly from assembly (assuming I'm running in real mode or ring 0). For instance say I want to load data from sectors 100-200 into some location in ram. How would I address a specific hard drive and how would I tell the drive what sectors I want?

Answer (score 5):

I agree with @joev that using BIOS calls is probably the easiest thing to do, but if you want to roll your own, it seems like you'll want to access the hardware directly.

For a PATA controller (or a SATA one set to compatibility mode), you can use PIO for simple data access. The OS Dev wiki has a great in depth article about it here: http://wiki.osdev.org/ATA_PIO_Mode

You can access the controllers through legacy I/O ports 0x1f0-0x1f7 (primary) and 0x170-0x177 (secondary). The following read example is from the wiki page:

> 1. Send 0xE0 for the "master" or 0xF0 for the "slave", ORed with the highest 4 bits of the LBA to port 0x1F6: outb(0x1F6, 0xE0 | (slavebit << 4) | ((LBA >> 24) & 0x0F))
> 2. Send a NULL byte to port 0x1F1, if you like (it is ignored and wastes lots of CPU time): outb(0x1F1, 0x00)
> 3. Send the sectorcount to port 0x1F2: outb(0x1F2, (unsigned char) count)
> 4. Send the low 8 bits of the LBA to port 0x1F3: outb(0x1F3, (unsigned char) LBA))
> 5. Send the next 8 bits of the LBA to port 0x1F4: outb(0x1F4, (unsigned char)(LBA >> 8))
> 6. Send the next 8 bits of the LBA to port 0x1F5: outb(0x1F5, (unsigned char)(LBA >> 16))
> 7. Send the "READ SECTORS" command (0x20) to port 0x1F7: outb(0x1F7, 0x20)
> 8. Wait for an IRQ or poll.
> 9. Transfer 256 words, a word at a time, into your buffer from I/O port 0x1F0. (In assembler, REP INSW works well for this.)
> 10. Then loop back to waiting for the next IRQ (or poll again -- see next note) for each successive sector.

There are also more sophisticated ways to access the drives (MMIO, more sophisticated PIO modes, DMA modes, etc.), but this is definitely a good starting place.

Answer (score 2):

The way you did this when dinosaurs roamed the earth was to use the "INT 13H" BIOS call, with AH set to 02H.  It may not even work on modern PCs in the SATA era.

Find more info [here](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0607.htm).  You'll probably get a better answer if you provide more detail in your question (ie, are you using some sort of OS, or is this some sort of "roll your own" project?)

Comment: "roll my own".  I'm trying to create my own OS and need to figure out how to set up a file system.

Comment: BIOS interrupt calls won't work in 32bit or 64bit protected mode.